# Layout gets cropped on round chin

Tags: android, wear-os, boxinsetlayout

The layout below gets cropped on a round chin `Wear` device. The round chin `Wear` device only displays the first `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lytLoginMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxedEdges="all">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDlgLogoutTitle"
            style="@style/Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Hi Employee #1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDlgLogoutMessage"
            style="@style/Details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/logout_msg"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDlgLogoutTitle" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

But my layout which got a `ScrollView` that contains a `ConstraintLayout` that contains 3 `TextView` and 2 `EditText` is displayed properly.

Both layouts are used for an `AlertDialog` and I don't know what is wrong with my layout.

UPDATE:
I tried to insert a new `TextView` under the second `TextView` and the second `TextView` got displayed now but the new `TextView` is not visible though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lytLogoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxedEdges="all">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDlgLogoutTitle"
            style="@style/Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Hi Ricky Manalo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDlgLogoutMessage"
            style="@style/Details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/logout_msg"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDlgLogoutTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDlgLogoutMessage" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

[image: This is a sample how my app looks like in a round chin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ?
More here:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts

Comment: It worked partially. My message got displayed but only the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Using @promanowicz's answer and increasing the `marginTop` and `marginBottom` of the message's `TextView`, I was able to display the full message `TextView`.

This is my final code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDlgLogoutMessage"
    style="@style/Details"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/logout_msg"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDlgLogoutTitle" />
```